# How to get the view fields in rows in the word document generated using Views data export module?

Tags: 7, views, importing-exporting

I am using [Views data export](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_data_export) module (version 7.x-3.1) to download content in Microsoft Word Format.

I am able to download the content but the fields of the view are coming out in columns rather than rows.

Please guide.

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative to using the [Views data export](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_data_export) module, you may want to use the [Forena](https://www.drupal.org/project/forena) module (disclosure: I'm a co-maintainer of it) to create a "report" that includes the data that you're interesting in (i.e. the "content" as in your question). As part of the report design, indicate which export formats you want to allow for exporting the data included in it. **DOC** (for MS Word) is one of the typical formats that are supported (apart from CSV,  XML, HTML, etc). By using [Forena](https://www.drupal.org/project/forena), the layout of the exported table (in your MS Word doc) would ***not***  be "*coming out in columns rather than rows*" (as in your question).

Have a look at the [Simple Table of States](http://drupal.placeto.be/reports/sample.states) example, and think of it as the equivalent of your "posts that you want to export". And note the hyperlinks in the upper right, which are:

- [CSV](http://drupal.placeto.be/reports/sample.states.csv).
- [XLS](http://drupal.placeto.be/reports/sample.states.xls).
- [HTML](http://drupal.placeto.be/reports/sample.states.html).
- [XML](http://drupal.placeto.be/reports/sample.states.xml).

Try any of these links to get the equivalent of the extracted information, but in the format you requested (there or other supported formats such as PDF, DOC, JSON, etc).

Checkout Forena's [Community Documentation](https://drupal.org/node/2041363) for (way) more details, and/or the [documentation that comes with the module](http://drupal.placeto.be/reports/help).

#### Forena versus Views

[Forena](https://www.drupal.org/project/forena) can be used together with the [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) module, or as an alternative to it, more specifically:

- As an ***alternative*** to Views, to create reports (and derivatives such as charts and/or exports of data) which you cannot, or not easily, create with only Views. E.g. to pivot data, where you want to create tables in the format of what in Forena is called "[Render a report in FrxCrosstab format](http://drupal.placeto.be/reports/help.renderers#frxcrosstab)".
- ***Integrated*** with Views, as explained in the [Forena tutorial pages](http://drupal.placeto.be/reports/help.sitebuilding#viewsrowstyle), i.e.:

> Using the Forena integration with the Views module, it is possible to use Forena reports as a views row style, so that in a view you can use the Forena templating engine to do the formatting. Although this can be done through the views templating engine Forena users may find they have more control with this engine.

Comment: Can you please guide on how to use forena with view. when i chose forena reports as views rows style, the content disappears in the view.

Comment: @TulikaSharma : check my updated answer (= Forena versus Views)